# Testing React Library with Jest created with projen

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ts-jest

I've set up a project to develop a react package (later released via NPM). To do that, I'm using [projen](https://github.com/projen/projen).

Since the library is a react library, with hooks, I set up the `.projenrc.ts` config file as follows

```js
import { typescript } from 'projen';
import { NpmAccess, TypeScriptJsxMode } from 'projen/lib/javascript';

const project = new typescript.TypeScriptProject({
  defaultReleaseBranch: 'main',
  name: 'NAME',
  projenrcTs: true,
  releaseToNpm: true,

  // Npm publishing
  npmAccess: NpmAccess.PUBLIC,
  packageName: 'PACKAGE-NAME',
  peerDeps: [
    'react@^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0 || ^18.0.0',
    'react-dom@^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0 || ^18.0.0',
  ],

  /* Dependencies */
  devDeps: [
    'react@^18.2.0',
    'react-dom@^18.2.0',
    '@types/react',
    '@types/react-dom',
  ],

  /* Extending tsconfig to accept .tsx files and JSX */
  tsconfig: {
    compilerOptions: {
      jsx: TypeScriptJsxMode.REACT_JSX,
    },
    include: ['src/**/*.tsx'],
  },
  tsconfigDev: {
    compilerOptions: {
      jsx: TypeScriptJsxMode.REACT_JSX,
    },
    include: ['src/**/*.tsx'],
  },

});

project.synth();
```

I can compile and use it into another react project with no problem. When it comes to testing, if I run `npx projen test` I get the following error

```
 Cannot find module 'react/jsx-runtime' from 'src/react/context/MyContext.tsx'
```

Looks like React is not installed correctly when launching jest testing. Since I don't want React to be in my dependencies, but at most in my dev dependencies, any advice on how to be able to run tests that involves .tsx files where react is imported?

FYI, this is the Jest part auto-generated by projen inside `package.json`

```json
{
  ...
  "jest": {
    "testMatch": [
      "<rootDir>/src/**/__tests__/**/*.ts?(x)",
      "<rootDir>/(test|src)/**/*(*.)@(spec|test).ts?(x)"
    ],
    "clearMocks": true,
    "collectCoverage": true,
    "coverageReporters": [
      "json",
      "lcov",
      "clover",
      "cobertura",
      "text"
    ],
    "coverageDirectory": "coverage",
    "coveragePathIgnorePatterns": [
      "/node_modules/"
    ],
    "testPathIgnorePatterns": [
      "/node_modules/"
    ],
    "watchPathIgnorePatterns": [
      "/node_modules/"
    ],
    "reporters": [
      "default",
      [
        "jest-junit",
        {
          "outputDirectory": "test-reports"
        }
      ]
    ],
    "preset": "ts-jest",
    "globals": {
      "ts-jest": {
        "tsconfig": "tsconfig.dev.json"
      }
    }
  },
  ...
}
```